# error in parsing an array in node.js, cannot access the members of the array

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am new to node.js , i wrote a code with two insert statements , i used a json input in postman
but after execution i could not access to the members of that array, but the other attributes name , price can be accessed, i do not understand why just players in the json can not be accecced and show undefined
result in console ??

here what i have tried in postman:

```
{
     "userid": 41,
    "name": "dhya",
    "price": 11,
    "players": [
        {
            "id":1,
            "firstname":"aa",
            "lastname":"ee",
            "position":"df",
            "price":12.1,
            "appearences":2,
            "goals":1,
            "assists":1,
            "cleansheets":1,
            "redcards":1,
            "yellowcards":1,
            "image":"qq",
            "clubid":2
        },
  {
            "id":2,
            "firstname":"aa",
            "lastname":"ee",
            "position":"df",
            "price":12.1,
            "appearences":2,
            "goals":1,
            "assists":1,
            "cleansheets":1,
            "redcards":1,
            "yellowcards":1,
            "image":"qq",
            "clubid":2
        }
    ]
     }
```

here what i tried in node.js

```
 create:(data,callback)=>{
  var myArray = [];
  for(item in data.players[0]) {
    console.log(item.id);
}
  var idsArray = myArray.map((obj) => obj.userid);  
  var id;
  console.log(id);
  pool.query(
      'insert into club(userid,name,price) values(?,?,?)',
   [
        data.userid,
        data.name,
        data.price
      ],
    
    
     /*   'insert into players(id,firstname,lastname,position,price,appearences,goals,assists,cleansheets,redcards,yellowcards,image,clubid) IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
        [ 
        myArray.id,
        myArray.firstname,
        myArray.lastname,
        myArray.position,
        myArray.price,
        myArray.appearences,
        myArray.goals,
        myArray.assists,
        myArray.cleansheets,
        myArray.redcards,
        myArray.yellowcards,
        myArray.image,
        idsArray,
        ],*/
       
  
      (error,results,fields)=>{
        if(error){
          callback(error);
        }
        id = results.insertId;
        return callback(null,results);
      },

     
      
      pool.query(
      
        'insert into players(id,firstname,lastname,position,price,appearences,goals,assists,cleansheets,redcards,yellowcards,image,clubid) IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
         [ 
         myArray.id,
         myArray.firstname,
         myArray.lastname,
         myArray.position,
         myArray.price,
         myArray.appearences,
         myArray.goals,
         myArray.assists,
         myArray.cleansheets,
         myArray.redcards,
         myArray.yellowcards,
         myArray.image,
         idsArray,
         ],
        
   
       (error,results,fields)=>{
         if(error){
           callback(error);
         }
        // id = results.insertId;
         return callback(null,results);
       },
      ),
    );
 
  },
```

the problem is in data of players in json which can not be accecced , i can get only the index of players when i loop like this

```
for(item in data.players) {
        console.log(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Node.js 8 or above, you can replace `for ... in` with  `for ... of`

```
for(let player of data.players) {
    console.log(player);
}
```

Comment: oh i can access but the array is not pushing the json

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access objects on the json :

```
myJson.userId
myJson.name
myJson.price
```

If you need to access objects in the "players" :

```
myJson.players.forEach((player) => {
   // now you can access to every player
   // example: console.log(player.id)
})
```